# Byte size of Packet

Tags: c#, .net, protocols, packet

I am trying to implement this protocol (http://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_RCON_Protocol) from a C# NET application. The part applicable there to the code I am implementing is under heading "Receiving". However, I am not positive I have the byte sizes correct when constructing the packet.

Here is my function to construct a packet...

```
    private static byte[] ConstructPacket(int request_id, int cmdtype, string cmd)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream))
        {
            byte[] cmdBytes = ConvertStringToByteArray(cmd);
            int packetSize = 12 + cmdBytes.Length;

            // Packet Contents
            writer.Write((int)packetSize); // Byte size of Packet not including This
            writer.Write((int)request_id);  // 4 Bytes
            writer.Write((int)cmdtype);     // 4 Bytes
            writer.Write(cmdBytes);         // 8 Bytes ??

            // NULL String 1
            writer.Write((byte)0x00);
            writer.Write((byte)0x00);

            // NULL String 2
            writer.Write((byte)0x00);
            writer.Write((byte)0x00);

            // Memory Stream to Byte Array
            byte[] buffer = stream.ToArray();

            return buffer;
        }
    }
```

According to the Protocol specifications, packetSize is the byte size of the packet not including itself.

The first 2 (int) would make it 8 bytes...
The "cmdBytes", which in this paticular instance is "testpass" would be 8 bytes I believe...
Then the final 2 null delimited strings (If I set these up right) would be 4 bytes.

So by my calculations, the packet should be 20 bytes big, but it doesn't seem to be working properly. Are the values I am thinking these should all be correct and am I setting the NULL delmited strings properly for C# .NET?

Answer (score 0):

You write two zeros too many.  Pretty easy to see in the examples, they all end with two zeros, not four.

Comment: What do you mean? Like this? // NULL String 1
            writer.Write((byte)0);
            writer.Write((byte)0);

Answer (score 0):

You should probably call `writer.Flush()` after the last `writer.Write()`. Otherwise you run the risk of disposing the writer before it's finished writing everything to the stream.